Calculating how many increments larger one value is compared to another
I have some incremental numerical data that has a specific range of values, where all increments is the double of the previous value, e.g. 0.064, 0.128, 0.256, 0.512, 1.024 ...
I want to calculate how many increments higher a specific value is to another. Based on this value I want to define that if this incremental change is equal to or larger than 3, the test value is TRUE. I cannot base this directly on the numerical value, as this will not reflect the incremental changes, e.g. the value 64 here would be 8 increments higher than 0.25, and not 256, as it would be if the actual numeric value was used.
library(dplyr)

testdata <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(0.25, 0.5, 2, 64, 32),
  var2 = c(0.064, 64, 32, 16, 0.128)
)



testdata %>%
  mutate(
    test = case_when(
      var1/var2 >= 3 ~ TRUE,
      TRUE ~ FALSE
    )
  )


Any ideas on how this could be done?

I don't think I understand what you are asking. Why does the value 2 jump to 64 in var1?  It is not clear if the data you provided is actually incorrect. Could you provide the expected result?

Do you want the calculation to always do var1 / var2, or should it get the highest number first?

I'm probably missing the subtlety, but doesn't var1/var2 >= 3 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE, ie. division answers this?

Yes, I was definitely missing the subtlety.

@Chris sorry not the easiest to explain!

What you want is the base 2 logarithm of the division between your two numbers. For instance, 64 / 0.25 = 256 = 2^8.
In R, you can use log to do that:
f <- function(x1, x2) log(x1 / x2, base = 2)
f(64, 0.25)
#[1] 8

With your data:
transform(testdata, test = f(var1, var2) >= 3)
#    var1   var2  test
# 1  0.25  0.064 FALSE
# 2  0.50 64.000 FALSE
# 3  2.00 32.000 FALSE
# 4 64.00 16.000 FALSE
# 5 32.00  0.128  TRUE


Thank you, this was indeed what I was looking for!

You can try log2 like below
> testdata$test <- Reduce(`-`, log2(testdata)) >= 3

> testdata
   var1   var2  test
1  0.25  0.064 FALSE
2  0.50 64.000 FALSE
3  2.00 32.000 FALSE
4 64.00 16.000 FALSE
5 32.00  0.128  TRUE

